# 5 blogs on one WordPress site

Tags: categories, multisite, author-template

What is the best way to have multiple blogs on one site? I am not talking about Multisite.

What I want is one website with 5 blogs. All accessible from one menu and editable from one backend, I could use categories, though I am looking for something else. Multisite would take a lot of tweaking.

Comment: Do you mean multiple categories of blogs?  Or multiple discrete blogs like CNN's blog site?

Comment: I don't know, just different pages with different things on them.

Comment: "Different pages with different things on them" doesn't explain a) what you're trying to do or b) why you don't want to use Multisite.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: yes give us some more clues here

Comment: You say you don't want multisite, and then when someone mentions multisite you say it's a good idea? "Different pages with different things on them"... is this a joke question?

Comment: No, it isn't, but I assumed he read the question.

Comment: What about custom post types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use [Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), yet still want to have multiple blogs with a common backend, another idea is:

- Customize your theme's [Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) so each author's "blog homepage" has a distinct design
- Create several different stylesheets, one per author. Use some conditional logic to display the appropriate stylesheet when viewing an individual blog post, so that the post matches that author's homepage design.
- Create several different [sidebars](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2007/11/how-to-create-multiple-dynamic-sidebars-for-wordpress-widgets/), one per author. This will allow you to have different widgets per author. You'll need conditional logic to know which sidebar to display too.

Of course, this would require quite a bit of tweaking too. Multisite might be less work.

Answer (score 8):

install WP3.0, use the mulisite feature and create a template in the first blog. This template has different loops and switch in each blog and use the content in the loop; use function switch_to_blog() for switch and then use default wp_query()
Also you can use import via RSS, maybe with plugins, maybe RSSimport, or own source

Comment: It has to have one backend for all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple blogs "on one site", do you mean each having a separate page?  If so, you should [create a network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) using subdirectories.

Comment: And have one backend.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that requirement.  I'd think your situation might be worth building support for into the network feature in WordPres 3. I could imagine it being somewhat common.